# Navigation Controller Toolbar Size & Location - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, toolbar

Hello I am currently working on an application in Swift 3.  I am having problems in a table view controller which is embedded in a navigation controller. I am currently displaying the navigationController toolbar.  However on the initial table view controller I set the navigation bar to hidden.  This results in the toolbar being resized and relocated.

Does anyone know how I can reload the toolbar to follow the following line of code: (This is called in view will appear)

```
self.navigationController?.toolbar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height-80, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 80)
```

I cannot find out how to resize the toolbar after hiding the navigation bar using the following: (This is called in view did appear)

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
```

Comment: Hi, Jerland did you try the below answer?

Comment: @aircraft YES! Thank you, it worked like a charm, it never occurred to me to manipulate the storyboard toolbar, i was attempting to do it all programmatically. Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could not resize your `toolbar` directly:

But you can inherit `UIToolbar` in your project:

```
import UIKit

class CustomToolbar: UIToolbar {

override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {

    var newSize: CGSize = super.sizeThatFits(size)
    newSize.height = 80  // there to set your toolbar height 

    return newSize
    }

}
```

In the `storyboard`:

[image: toolbar's class set to CustomToolbar]

The result, height of toolbar is 80:

[image: the height is 80 now]

Comment: @Jerland2 The first you must know the `UIToolbar` in `NavigationController ` is readonly, you can validate this in program, and the `customToolbar` is your best choice to `replicate functionality like the Apple Music now playing toolbar`

Comment: Sorry deleted comment, i misunderstood your storyboard at first, it has been solved, thank you!

Comment: This does not seem to work for swift 4.  Does anyone have a work-around? Specifically for NavigationController's Toolbar, like in this question. Thanks.